# How to use objects variables (var_dump)?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I just var_dump'ed object and got something like this:

```
    object(simple_html_dom)#1 (23) { ["root"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { 
["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(3) ["tag"]=> string(4) "text" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> *RECURSION* ["_"]=> array(1) { [4]=> string(51) "'http://www.lnik.com/num' 'http://www.lnik.com/com'" } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> *RECURSION* } } ["parent"]=> NULL ["_"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(-1) [1]=> int(2) } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> *RECURSION* } ["nodes"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(3) ["tag"]=> string(4) "text" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> *RECURSION* ["_"]=> array(1) { [4]=> string(51) "'http://www.lnik.com/num' 'http://www.lnik.com/com'" } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> *RECURSION* } } ["parent"]=> NULL ["_"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(-1) [1]=> int(2) } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> *RECURSION* } [1]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(3) ["tag"]=> string(4) "text" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> *RECURSION* } ["parent"]=> NULL ["_"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(-1) [1]=> int(2) } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> *RECURSION* } ["_"]=> array(1) { [4]=> string(51) "'http://www.lnik.com/num' 'http://www.lnik.com/com'" } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> *RECURSION* } } ["callback"]=> NULL ["lowercase"]=> bool(true) ["original_size"]=> int(51) ["size"]=> int(51) ["pos":protected]=> int(51) ["doc":protected]=> string(51) "'http://www.lnik.com/num' 'http://www.lnik.com/com'" ["char":protected]=> NULL ["cursor":protected]=> int(2) ["parent":protected]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(3) ["tag"]=> string(4) "text" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> *RECURSION* ["_"]=> array(1) { [4]=> string(51) "'http://www.lnik.com/num' 'http://www.lnik.com/com'" } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> *RECURSION* } } ["parent"]=> NULL ["_"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(-1) [1]=> int(2) } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> *RECURSION* } ["noise":protected]=> array(0) { } ["token_blank":protected]=> string(4) " " ["token_equal":protected]=> string(4) " =/>" ["token_slash":protected]=> string(6) " /> " ["token_attr":protected]=> string(2) " >" ["_charset"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" ["_target_charset"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" ["default_br_text":protected]=> string(2) " " ["default_span_text"]=> string(1) " " ["self_closing_tags":protected]=> array(9) { ["img"]=> int(1) ["br"]=> int(1) ["input"]=> int(1) ["meta"]=> int(1) ["link"]=> int(1) ["hr"]=> int(1) ["base"]=> int(1) ["embed"]=> int(1) ["spacer"]=> int(1) } ["block_tags":protected]=> array(6) { ["root"]=> int(1) ["body"]=> int(1) ["form"]=> int(1) ["div"]=> int(1) ["span"]=> int(1) ["table"]=> int(1) } ["optional_closing_tags":protected]=> array(11) { ["tr"]=> array(3) { ["tr"]=> int(1) ["td"]=> int(1) ["th"]=> int(1) } ["th"]=> array(1) { ["th"]=> int(1) } ["td"]=> array(1) { ["td"]=> int(1) } ["li"]=> array(1) { ["li"]=> int(1) } ["dt"]=> array(2) { ["dt"]=> int(1) ["dd"]=> int(1) } ["dd"]=> array(2) { ["dd"]=> int(1) ["dt"]=> int(1) } ["dl"]=> array(2) { ["dd"]=> int(1) ["dt"]=> int(1) } ["p"]=> array(1) { ["p"]=> int(1) } ["nobr"]=> array(1) { ["nobr"]=> int(1) } ["b"]=> array(1) { ["b"]=> int(1) } ["option"]=> array(1) { ["option"]=> int(1) } } }
```

How can I echo some varbiables of object ? Tried $object->link; etc. but not working

Comment: that is not the way `simple_html_dom` works .. where is your code and what are you trying to do

Comment: that was a bit too fast.. I got what i want simply by echoing variable. (the links)

Comment: `$html->load_file('array.htm');
echo $html;`

Comment: are you trying to search for links in the `html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I echo some variables of object ?

The [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) function is for debugging information about a concrete variable. In your case it tells you that the variable or expression you dump is an object of type `simple_html_dom` and outputs some additional information:

```
object(simple_html_dom) #1 (23) { 
    ["root"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { 
        ["nodetype"]=> int(5) 
        ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) {} 
        ["children"]=> array(0) {}
        ["nodes"]=> array(1) {
            ...
```

As this shows this has some strucutre, `var_dump` tries to traverse the values of the properties of that object, too.

However, the way you posted the output in your question therefore makes it extremely difficult to actually see these. Consider to make line-breaks and whitespace visible, for example, if you have that copied from your browser, use the view-source feature of your browser first to actually see these line-breaks.

This normally makes it a no-brainer to find out which object properties actually exist and which not.

```
 $object->link;
```

Is that long-time not working it does not exist. Also as each object can be different, check the documentation of the simple html dom library how to use it. It might define own accessors through so called [*magic methods*](http://php.net/language.oop5.magic) - `var_dump` does not see these, it is only about the bare values.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$object->root->link
```

there is two level of objects.

i hope this help

Comment: I thought this gonna help too. But the only worked for now here was `echo $object;`